# Touchend will cancel on canvas and doesnt fires

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a weird problem. I'm creating a test game.Which uses touch events and canvas.There is a ball that you can push it and when you release your finger it must go(something like angry birds).
I made that in mouse and it work correctly.I wanna make it on android. But it doesn't run.But when you use 2 finger it works correctly.
I'm sure the problem is here :

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.touches[0].clientX >= x && event.touches[0].clientX <= x + (radius * 2) && event.touches[0].clientY >= y && event.touches[0].clientY <= y + (radius * 2)) {
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        isindrag = true;
        oldx = x;
        oldy = y;
    }
});
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isindrag) {
        x = event.touches[0].clientX;
        y = event.touches[0].clientY;
    }
});
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
    var touchX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    var touchY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    if (isindrag && touchX < canvas.width && touchY < canvas.height && touchX > 0 && touchY > 0) {
        isindrag = false;
        dx = -(x - oldx) / 30;
        dy = -(y - oldy) / 30;
        ismoving = true;
    }
});
canvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

x : x of ball
y : y of ball
dx : Delta x of ball
dy : delta y of ball
radius : radius of ball

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `touches` object of a touch event contains a collection of points currently on the screen. Now imagine that you put a single finger onto the surface and release it. This will trigger a `touchend` event but as the `touches` object just contains information on the active 'fingers', it will come up empty thus there is no `clientX` or `clientY` property to query. In a `touchend` event handler you need to use `changedTouches` instead of touches.

So try changing

```
var touchX = event.touches[0].clientX;
var touchY = event.touches[0].clientY;
```

to

```
var touchX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
var touchY = event.changedTouches[0].clientY;
```

Comment: thank you so much it was so useful it was my problem for months